# Colorize output with different color

Tags: bash, colors, grep, ansi-escape

I need to colour output using ANSI color for example in blue then we cat a file.
But if we grep word error in file this words must be colored red

I try to use grep --colour=always but it reset the coloring to default after word match

For example my console is blue text now, but if i use

```
cat test.txt | grep -E --color=auto '.*line.*|$'
this is line 2 <<<---this line is red
just doing something <<<- this line is black
```

[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1gGY.jpg)

And i need console back to blue color

I expect console back to blue color

Comment: `just doing something` doesn't match your grep expression, why is it printed at all?

Comment: it does - the regex is grepping for `|$` -> ".*line.* or alternatively the end of line"

Comment: @jordanm because of |$ . Tyler Stoney is right

Comment: Ah, I see, I missed that part. This is expected behavior because grep only colors the part that matches (what would be displayed if you had used `grep -o`). In this case it can't add color to the end of the line.

Comment: @jordanm did you know any command which can color only needed word in red but preserve color output of console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mess with the `GREP_COLORS` environment variable before running `grep`.

```bash
GREP_COLORS='sl=36:cx=36' grep -E '.*line.*|$' filename
```

will color the 'selected line' and 'context line' in the escape color code you set it to (36 being cyan, in this example)

I will happily give credit to the answer here to use for more reference:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/705097/default-value-for-the-grep-colors-environment-variable

If you still need the terminal colors to be cyan (or whatever color you originally chose) after the grep runs, I'd try just echoing the escape sequence after your call to grep.

Side note: run your script through shellcheck, cat is redundant with grep. Instead of
`cat filename | grep mystring` just use `grep mystring filename`

Comment: Its works in bash console  but not work in Jenkins(((

Comment: does jenkins output terminal colors? When my team used it, all ansi escape codes would be literally printed in the output text

Comment: i think no, i use ansi color and print escape codes too, but if use this - cat test.txt | grep -E --color=auto '.*line.*|$'  - whole line "this is line 2" colored red in Jenkins too. I do my best to search solution to color cat output blue but line with word  "line" in red and can't find any solutions

Comment: What is the **exact** line you gave to Jenkins? I don't know much about Jenkins, but if grep is able to colorize *some* characters in such a way that Jenkins can parse it, I suspect it should be able to colorize *any* set of characters in that way. If you're still doing a `cat | grep,` then setting the GREP_COLORS inline won't have any effect if it's in front of `cat`. Put simply, `GREP_COLORS='blah' cat filename | grep regex` won't colorize even in a terminal; use `cat filename | GREP_COLORS='blah' grep regex`

Comment: @TylerStoney there is an plugin for everything in jenkins, including translating ASNI color to html for its log view. https://plugins.jenkins.io/ansicolor/

Comment: @diyes92182 I think on jenkins you likely need `--color=always` with this.

Comment: @jordanm yes! You right now it works as expected. I can't  give you a point,because system not allowed it. Thanks also to Tyler Stoney! So working line for jenkins is  GREP_COLORS='sl=36:cx=36' grep --color=always -E '.*line.*|$' filename